# JS Confirm Popup after Button Link Loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a link that serves 2 purposes: (1)To direct the user to an outside link by opening a new tab (2)To confirm that they performed a specific action in that outside link and notify admin if they confirm this.

I would like the follow sequence to occur:

1. User clicks link and is directed to and outside link (ie www.google.com), meanwhile the confirm message pops up in the original page
2. User performs the action (or not)
3. User returns to the original page and sees a confirmation popup saying "Please confirm that you performed the action"
4. If the user clicks OK, '/dashboard/notify/admin/' is called and admin is notified that the action was performed (this works fine).

Currently, I can only get the confirm popup to appear prior to the user being directed to the outside link. Is there a way to direct the user to the outside link immediately and have the confirm popup waiting on the original page for them to confirm when they return?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.goal-completed').click(function(){

  var ss = confirm('Please confirm that you performed the action');

  if(ss){
   var id, data, url = '/dashboard/notify/admin/'
   id = $(this).attr('task-id');
   data = {id: id};
   $.post(url, data, function(r){
    if(r.response == 'OK'){
     alert('We will confirm and give you the points that you earned!');
    }
   });
  }
 })
});
```

```html
<section class="dashboard-section">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="blue register-title">Link and email test</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="goal-completed" task-id="6" task-name="Test">Link & Email</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: You can't redirect a user out of your website, and expect that when they return, the `click` event will continue from the point they left. It just doesn't work that way

Comment: I am opening the new link in a different tab, so my website is still on the same page. Can't the popup just pop out as a confirmation before notifying admin while allowing the link to open up a new tab prior to the user answering the popup?

Comment: Try wrapping ALL the code inside the click function with `setTimeout(function(){ var ss = confirm('Please confirm that you performed the action'); ....  }, 100);`

Comment: Thank you, this comes very close. The only problem is that, while I am initially directed to the outside link, when the popup appears 100ms later I am forced back to the original tab on Chrome. Is there any way for the popup to just appear without forcing the user back to the website?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

1. The user taps the button
2. The new window opens with the other URL
3. The popup opens, and the user can confirm. The look of this popup will be different in different browsers. In Safari, for example, the popup will not appear until the user goes back to the original window/tab, but in Chrome, it will appear immediately.

**You can test this snippet here: http://jworldhosting.com/Uploads/StackOverflow/windowOpenAlert.html as the StackOverflow snippets appear to block the demonstration of the alert and url change.**

```js
function loadAlert() {
  window.open("http://www.google.com", '_blank');

  var ss = confirm('Please confirm that you performed the action');

  if (ss) {
    var id, data, url = '/dashboard/notify/admin/'
    id = $(this).attr('task-id');
    data = {
      id: id
    };
    $.post(url, data, function(r) {
      if (r.response == 'OK') {
        alert('We will confirm and give you the points that you earned!');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="dashboard-section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="blue register-title">Link and email test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <a href="javascript:loadAlert();" class="goal-completed" id="goal-completed" task-id="6" task-name="Test">Link & Email</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You're missing `}` at the end of the function

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks for letting me know. I have updated the answer with the revised syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. On Chrome the popup follows me around, no matter which tab I am on, effectively forcing me to answer it before doing anything else on the page. Any way to avoid this? It seems that each browser works differently with this so maybe the best solution is just having 2 separate buttons...

Comment: @wraasch What about creating an alert out of an HTML div instead of a native alert? Then it would stay on the page. You could insert the HTML into the DOM and remove it in the loadAlert() method. Something like this: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide an update on the final solution. I ended up using HTML to create the popup as a hidden modal and removing the hidden class upon clicking the link button.  Everything works as needed now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.goal-completed').click(function() {

    var id, data, url = '/dashboard/notify/admin/'
    id = $(this).attr('task-id');
    data = {
      id: id
    };
    $.post(url, data, function(r) {
      if (r.response == 'OK') {
        alert('We will confirm and give you the points that you earned!');
      }
    });
  })
  $('.goal-pop').click(function(event) {
    $("#modal").removeClass('hidden');
    $("#goal-confirm").removeClass('hidden');
    $("#close").removeClass('hidden');
    $("#overlay").removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#modal {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 14px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
#goal-confirm {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
#close {
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 27px;
  display: block;
  top: 9px;
  right: -1px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.btn-yesno {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.btn-goals {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.btn-action {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #F5A623;
```

```html
<section class="dashboard-section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-block btn-goals goal-pop">Complete Task</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='overlay' class='hidden'></div>
  <div id='modal' class='hidden'>
    <div id='goal-confirm' class='hidden'>
      Did you complete the task?</strong>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <a href="/dashboard" class="goal-completed btn btn-block btn-yesno btn-yes">Yes</a>
          <a href="/dashboard" class="btn btn-block btn-yesno btn-no">No</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href='#' id='close' class='hidden'>X</a>
  </div>
</section>
{% endblock %} {% block javascript %}
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.csrf.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/goal.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```